# Swift and Parse iOS SDK findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock(): unable to correctly use CollectionView

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform

I want to have a setup like Instagram's feed where there are two sections made from a Collection View Controller (header and cell).  Unfortunately, when the query is called and after I've passed in the PFObjects to my local array, the data source/delegate methods get called but the local array isn't quite loaded yet and thus a fatal index error occurs.

My goal is to load the comments per post (section header) based on the indexPath of the header view.  Is this approach wrong?  Should I just load it into as a JSON-like object and iterate through indexPath?

```
class dummyVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    // Local arrays
    var feedPost = [PFObject]()
    var feedComments: [String] = []
    var followingPeople: [String] = []

    var page = 10
    // Reference to our collection view in Interface Builder
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self


        self.loadPosts()

        // Causes "fatal error: index out of range" because self.feedPost is nil for a few seconds...
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleSupplementaryElementsOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
        self.loadCurrentComments(indexPath[0])


}

    func loadPosts() {

        // 1) Return followers
        let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "follow")
        followQuery.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork


        // obtain all the entries such that it looks like (follower: me, following: [ ] )
        followQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: "Robin")
        followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                self.followingPeople.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for object in objects! {

                    self.followingPeople.append(object.objectForKey("following") as! String)

            }

                // Add ourself to the list because we want to see our posts too
                self.followingPeople.append("Robin")

                // 2) Return our posts and theirs
                let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "posts")
                postQuery.cachePolicy = .CacheElseNetwork
                postQuery.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.followingPeople)
                postQuery.limit = self.page
                postQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
                postQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        // 3) Add those posts to our array
                        self.feedPost.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                        self.feedPost = objects!
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }

                    else {
                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                }

            }) // Inner block completion



        }
            else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

    }) // Outer block completion
}

    func loadCurrentComments(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


        let commentQuery = PFQuery(className: "comments")

        commentQuery.whereKey("postID", equalTo: self.feedPost[indexPath.section])
        commentQuery.limit = 2
        commentQuery.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")
        commentQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) in


            if error == nil {

                self.feedComments.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for object in objects! {

                    self.feedComments.append(object.objectForKey("commentText") as! String)

            }
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: to be absolutely sure: is indexPath causing the error or which line exact? It seems you are calling the function before the data is even reloaded.

Comment: This line right here: self.loadCurrentComments(indexPath[0])